# Was quarantine continued after Apollo 11?

Tags: apollo-program, quarantine

After returning from the Apollo 11 mission, astronauts were [placed in quarantine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_11#Splashdown_and_quarantine) for 18 days (July 24 - August 10, 1969).

[image: The crew of Apollo 11 in quarantine after returning to Earth, visited by Richard Nixon]

<sup>Photo: The crew of Apollo 11 in [quarantine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarantine) after returning to Earth, visited by Richard Nixon (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo_11_crew_in_quarantine.jpg))</sup>

Was this (useless) practice continued after that mission?

Comment: Devil's advocate: why would one data point (Apollo 11) suggest the entire moon was barren of life?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_11#Splashdown_and_quarantine), it continued for the Apollo 12 & 14 missions as well.

> This practice would continue for **two more Apollo missions, Apollo 12 and Apollo 14**, before the Moon was proven to be barren of life and the quarantine process dropped.